# Refinements on a string field

Tags: 2013, fast-search, refiner, string, fast

Can I split the value in a string field for the refinements?
For example If I have values on a string field that looks like: "ABC,DEF" when I apply the refinements to that field I obtain "ABC,DEF" as a refiner.

Is there a way that i can obtain:
"ABC,DEF","ABC","DEF" as a refiners?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode 0x2029. Take a look at https://searchunleashed.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/working-with-fast-search-for-sharepoint-and-multivalued-properties/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this just works for SharePoint 2010. Do you have any information about SharePoint 2013?

Comment: For 2013 you must use Content enrichment :(